# Spark: Creating dataframe from rdd with schema using values from rdd

Tags: apache-spark

Assuming I am having the following rdd:

```
val aSeq = Seq(("a",Seq(("aa",1.0),("bb",2.0),("cc",3.0))),
               ("b",Seq(("aa",3.0),("bb",4.0),("cc",5.0))),
               ("c",Seq(("aa",6.0),("bb",7.0),("cc",8.0))),
               ("d",Seq(("aa",9.0),("bb",10.0),("cc",11.0))))

val anRdd = sc.parallelize(aSeq)
```

How can I create a dataframe which uses the first values from the Sequence to name and stracture the schema? If I transform it to df I got the following:

```
val aDF = anRDD.toDF("id","column2")
aDF.printSchema

root
  |---id: string
  |---column2: array
         |---- element: struct
                 |-----_1: string
                 |-----_2: double
```

To be more clear what I want is something like the following:

```
root
 |--id: String(nullable = true)
 |--column2:struct (nullable = true)
        |----aa: Double
        |----bb: Double
        |----cc: Double
```

**Edit**

@eliasah gave a pretty understandable answer which give the desired output. I tried to implimented in a my real example, which is more 'deep'/nested. To illustrate I give the following example of an one level more that the first example:

```
val aSeq = Seq(("a",Seq(("aa",(("aaa",1.0),("bbb",Array(2.0,2.0)))),("bb",(("aaa",8.0),("bbb",Array(3.0,4.0)))),("cc",(("aaa",4.0),("bbb",Array(9.0,3.0)))))),
               ("b",Seq(("aa",(("aaa",1.0),("bbb",Array(3.0,2.0)))),("bb",(("aaa",8.0),("bbb",Array(3.0,3.0)))),("cc",(("aaa",4.0),("bbb",Array(3.0,9.0)))))),
               ("c",Seq(("aa",(("aaa",1.0),("bbb",Array(3.0,2.0)))),("bb",(("aaa",8.0),("bbb",Array(3.0,3.0)))),("cc",(("aaa",4.0),("bbb",Array(3.0,9.0)))))),
               ("d",Seq(("aa",(("aaa",1.0),("bbb",Array(3.0,2.0)))),("bb",(("aaa",8.0),("bbb",Array(3.0,3.0)))),("cc",(("aaa",4.0),("bbb",Array(3.0,9.0)))))))

val anRddB = sc.parallelize(aSeqB)
```

How can I have a DF with the following schema:

```
root
 |--id: String
 |--column2:struct
       |----aa:struct
             |--aaa:Double
             |--bbb:array
                 |--element: double
       |----bb:struct
             |--aaa:Double
             |--bbb:array
                 |--element: double
       |----cc:struct
             |--aaa:Double
             |--bbb:array
                 |--element: double
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the solution isn't pretty but here it is. You'll need to import the `struct` function :

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct
// import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct

scala> val seq = Seq(("a",Seq(("aa",(("aaa",1.0),("bbb",Array(2.0,2.0)))),("bb",(("aaa",8.0),("bbb",Array(3.0,4.0)))),("cc",(("aaa",4.0),("bbb",Array(9.0,3.0)))))),
           ("b",Seq(("aa",(("aaa",1.0),("bbb",Array(3.0,2.0)))),("bb",(("aaa",8.0),("bbb",Array(3.0,3.0)))),("cc",(("aaa",4.0),("bbb",Array(3.0,9.0)))))),
           ("c",Seq(("aa",(("aaa",1.0),("bbb",Array(3.0,2.0)))),("bb",(("aaa",8.0),("bbb",Array(3.0,3.0)))),("cc",(("aaa",4.0),("bbb",Array(3.0,9.0)))))),
           ("d",Seq(("aa",(("aaa",1.0),("bbb",Array(3.0,2.0)))),("bb",(("aaa",8.0),("bbb",Array(3.0,3.0)))),("cc",(("aaa",4.0),("bbb",Array(3.0,9.0)))))))

scala> val anRdd = sc.parallelize(seq)
```

Convert your `column2` to a Map :

```
scala> val df = anRDD.map(x => (x._1, x._2.toMap)).toDF("x", "y")
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [x: string, y: map<string,double>]
```

Pull up the first set of fields :

```
scala> val df2 = df.select($"x".as("id"), struct($"y".getItem("aa").as("aa"),$"y".getItem("bb").as("bb"),$"y".getItem("cc").as("cc")).as("column2"))
// df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, column2: struct<aa:struct<_1:struct<_1:string,_2:double>,_2:struct<_1:string,_2:array<double>>>,bb:struct<_1:struct<_1:string,_2:double>,_2:struct<_1:string,_2:array<double>>>,cc:struct<_1:struct<_1:string,_2:double>,_2:struct<_1:string,_2:array<double>>>>]

scala> df2.printSchema
// root
//  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- column2: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- aa: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- _1: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- _2: double (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |-- _2: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- _2: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = false)
//  |    |-- bb: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- _1: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- _2: double (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |-- _2: struct (nullable = true)

scala> df2.show(false)
// +---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// |id |column2                                                                                                                     |
// +---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// |a  |[[[aaa,1.0],[bbb,WrappedArray(2.0, 2.0)]],[[aaa,8.0],[bbb,WrappedArray(3.0, 4.0)]],[[aaa,4.0],[bbb,WrappedArray(9.0, 3.0)]]]|
// |b  |[[[aaa,1.0],[bbb,WrappedArray(3.0, 2.0)]],[[aaa,8.0],[bbb,WrappedArray(3.0, 3.0)]],[[aaa,4.0],[bbb,WrappedArray(3.0, 9.0)]]]|
// |c  |[[[aaa,1.0],[bbb,WrappedArray(3.0, 2.0)]],[[aaa,8.0],[bbb,WrappedArray(3.0, 3.0)]],[[aaa,4.0],[bbb,WrappedArray(3.0, 9.0)]]]|
// |d  |[[[aaa,1.0],[bbb,WrappedArray(3.0, 2.0)]],[[aaa,8.0],[bbb,WrappedArray(3.0, 3.0)]],[[aaa,4.0],[bbb,WrappedArray(3.0, 9.0)]]]|
// +---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Update:** To follow up the question update, I'll use the DataFrame `df2` to continue pull up the nested fields. It is a bit tricky but here it goes :

```
val df3 = df2.select(
    $"id",
    struct(
        struct($"column2.aa._1".getItem("_2").as("aaa"),$"column2.aa._2".getItem("_2").as("bbb")).as("aa"),
        struct($"column2.bb._1".getItem("_2").as("aaa"),$"column2.bb._2".getItem("_2").as("bbb")).as("bb"),
        struct($"column2.cc._1".getItem("_2").as("aaa"),$"column2.cc._2".getItem("_2").as("ccc")).as("cc")
    ).as("column2")
)
// df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, column2: struct<aa:struct<aaa:double,bbb:array<double>>,bb:struct<aaa:double,bbb:array<double>>,cc:struct<aaa:double,ccc:array<double>>>]
```

There is no magic here, you need to understand well the gymnastics of `struct` types and nested types to be able to combine it a get the expected output :

```
df3.printSchema
// root
//  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- column2: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- aa: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |-- aaa: double (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- bbb: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = false)
//  |    |-- bb: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |-- aaa: double (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- bbb: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = false)
//  |    |-- cc: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |-- aaa: double (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- ccc: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = false)
```

**Note:** Tested with spark-shell 2.0

Comment: I am maybe mistaken considering your example, but please explain further what kind of relationship should be between your nested fields.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I cant reproduce it. From which library is `struct` imported?

Comment: you should import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct

Comment: Its correct, but I was unable to implemented in a more 'deep' format. I have updated my question. Have a look if you got any spare time. Thanks :)

Comment: @MpizosDimitris this got messy but I think that I have it. I hope that you get how it goes.

Comment: Thanks eliasah. I managed yesterday night to do it :) thanks for the help!